# How to make existing forms deriven from a base form in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have an existing project in VB.net with many Windows forms.I want to change all forms to deriven from a base form created in a class library.
is there any way to do so?

if i do inheritance with a code like this the designer dose not show the child form and gets error

Class Form1
    Inherits BaseFormLibrary.BaseForm

Comment: You'll need to edit the code to change the `inherits` clause in each applicable class.

Comment: Can you explain more please?is it means i need to declare all forms again?

Comment: Setting the base class for another is pretty fundamental to VB programming, if you have questions about it you need to find an introductory tutorial (but [SO] does not do tutorial recommendations).

Comment: Google serach yileds exactly what you need : [How to: Inherit Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s82eeh07(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), [Windows Forms Visual Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Go to each of your forms designer code class. Inside towards the top you will see the inherits statment. Change what it inherits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to change existing forms to inherit another base class you need to change each form that you want to take effect and change what they inherit.

Go to each of your forms designer code class. Inside towards the top you will see the inherits statment. Change what it inherits.

Comment: I tested this solution before in c#. but doesn't works. however in VB works!